# testcafe: click a button if it's enabled, otherwise fail

Tags: javascript, testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe

I want to click a button if it's enabled, otherwise fail.  I know how to do this in an inconvenient way:

```
.expect(
  Selector('button')        
    .hasAttribute('disabled')
)
.notOk()
.click(Selector('button'))
```

but that's a lot of code for one "thought." Is there a way to do this with one selector/line? The problem is, there doesn't seem to be a `doesNotHaveAttribute` function.

Comment: Not related to testcafe but have tried using xPath and document.evaluate ?

Comment: @Berto99 isn't that the opposite of what I want?

Comment: @DanielKaplan yep, sorry, i meant `button:enabled`

Comment: @Berto99 that worked. I forgot that selector exists.

Comment: @Berto99 I figured you may not know testcafe. See my answer below and copy and paste it and I will accept it

Comment: @DanielKaplan yep sorry ahah btw, posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:enabled) for this so you can do this:

```
.click(Selector('button:enabled'))
```